# How to make Sublime Text give preference to words in the current file buffer for autocomplete?

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have some custom completions in my ST3 user directory.
When I start typing, the autocomplete suggestions show up from my completions just fine. However, this gets in the way of completions which are in the buffer.

e.g.

Say I have the word **'prime-squares'** in my current file buffer.
Now somewhere else in the file, I start to type **'pri..'** and all I see are suggestions from my completions files. And not until I almost type the full word **'prime-square..'** does the autocomplete suggestion for **'prime-squares'** show up.

Which completely defeats the purpose of autocomplete.

Please note that autocomplete suggestions run out after say typing **'prime-..'**, and yet the suggestion **'prime-squares'** doesn't show up until I've typed some more.

Is there a way to set weights for suggestions?

Or set them up in such a way, that the matching words in the current file always show up first, along with any other suggestions from completions files at the bottom?

Comment: Can you provide a small example file that illustrates this in action? There are a few things that might be getting in the way and/or kicking you in the butt and it's hard to say which without more context.

Comment: @OdatNurd Do you mean a completion file from the User dir? 
Here's a link to a screen capture video that demonstrates the problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gaD-1np4M4E

Comment: And here's one completion file: https://pastebin.com/guqPYhV6

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware there's way to weight the order in which the completions in the auto-complete popup are presented. This seems to be confirmed by the section on [Completions](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/completions.html) in the [Unofficial Docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/index.html), which say:

> These are the sources for completions the user can control, in the order they are prioritized:
>
> ```
> 1. Snippets
> 2. API-injected completions via on_query_completions()
> 3. Completions files
> ```
>
> Additionally, the following completions are folded into the final list:
>
> ```
> 4. Words in the buffer
> ```

That said, some quick testing seems to indicate that the presence of even a single completion with a trigger that matches words in the buffer stops those words from appearing in the completions list.

[image: Completions Sample]

As seen here, without any completions both words that start with `co` and words that start with `di` will cause words from the buffer to appear in the completions list. Introducing a completion with a trigger that contains the text `disjoin` stops those matching buffer words from appearing, although the other words still do.

As far as I can see, it's doing that by design, as I haven't been able to determine any setting that may get around that. If that's the case you may need to make a feature request or check if someone has l[ogged this as an issue](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues) already, as it may also be a bug.

Admittedly I don't use completions a lot, so there may be some way around this that I'm unaware of.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Checked the issues queue, nothing popped up. But your answer does help confirm that this is reproducible. Think it can be solved though. Going to attempt a few things..